# Divisors on a complex torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm asked to prove the following fact:

*On a complex torus $X$ every canonical divisor is principal and vice-versa.*

At this moment I know only the basic properties of divisors and that, if $K$ is a canonical divisor on $X$, then $\operatorname{deg} (K) = 0$. Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Comment: You can use the fact that $K$ is the trivial bundle, then the line bundle associated to $D$ is trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by "trivial bundle" and "bundle associated to $D$"?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is writing out an explicit canonical divisor. For example, if $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are local coordinates of the torus $X=\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$, then $dz_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dz_n$ is a well-defined $n$-form on $X$. The divisor it defines is obviously the zero divisor, since it is nowhere vanishing. The zero divisor, in turn, is equal to the divisor of a constant function, and you have what you are looking for.

Comment: In this way you prove that a particular canonical divisor is principal.
How this implies that "every" canonical divisor is principal?

Comment: If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two canonical divisors, then $K_1-K_2$ is principal. This is because "dividing" two forms gives you a well-defined meromorphic function. Therefore if $K_1$ is principal then $K_2$ must also be principal.